# Save state of redux store during development

Tags: reactjs, redux

How can I hydrate my redux store with a JSON file (that was previously export from Redux dev tools) for development purposes (to avoid call to database) ?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this without using Redux Dev Tools' import button?

Comment: yes. Ideally, I'll have the file that should be used to bootstrap the store in my working dir, and if NODE_ENV=dev, then redux should look for and load data from that file when the store is being created.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of this? Anyway:

1. Set a breakpoint at where you hydrate your store (e.g. `let store = createStore(todoApp, window.STATE_FROM_SERVER)`)
2. Overwrite `window.STATE_FROM_SERVER` in the console with the JSON that you exported before.
3. Continue running your script.

Obviously the checksums are going to mismatch if you are using server-side rendering.

Comment: I was hoping to speed up minor UI changes that require data to display.

Comment: this is what I was looking for https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader